# SSL certificate error with wildcard subdomain @AWS route53 aliased to an ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-route53, wildcard-subdomain

## The setup

Route53 record(***.testing.domain.com**) linked to an ELB(which uses an Amazon Certificate Manger issued certificate for ***.domain.com** and **domain.com**)

The targets of the ELB are running **nginx** which inturn **proxy_pass**es the incoming requests to a (django)server running on port 80xx (ex: 127.0.0.1:8099).

Note: *The nginx server listens to requests on port 80 and 443* and *the targets of the ELB are registered on ports 80 and 443*.

## QUESTION:

I am able to access the following:

- **http**://domain.com
- **https**://domain.com
- **http**://any.subdomain.domain.com

I want to know why I am getting a `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` when I'm trying to access **https**://**any.subdomain.domain.com**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need request another certificate for `*.subdomain.domain.com`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-certificate.html

> *.example.com can protect login.example.com and test.example.com, but it cannot protect test.login.example.com. Also note that *.example.com
>   protects only the subdomains of example.com, it does not protect the
>   bare or apex domain (example.com). However, you can request a
>   certificate that protects a bare or apex domain and its subdomains by
>   specifying multiple domain names in your request.